# Local variable collect defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final

Tags: java

I'm getting an error *Local variable collect defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final* at collect. I tried declaring the **collect** at class level surrouning with final but still I'm getting same error.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!

my code

```
@Override
    public List<FinalAssessment> getFactorsChild(String pid) {
        
        //probationer fa performance 
        List<FinalAssessment> probationerFa = faAssessment.getProbationerFa(pid);
        
        //master factors
        List<FinalAssessment> factorsChild = faAssessment.getFactorsChild();
        /*
         * Setting marked performance grades to the factorschild list to show marked
         * performance grades in list
         */ 
        
        probationerFa.forEach(fa-> {
            if(fa.getGradecode()!=null) {
                collect = factorsChild.stream().
                filter(l->l.getGradecode().equals(fa.getItemcode())).
                peek(pfa-> pfa.setGradecode(fa.getGradecode())).collect(Collectors.toList());
            }
        });
        
        collect.forEach( x-> System.out.println("G code " + x.getGradecode()));
        
        return faAssessment.getFactorsChild();
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The error you get just means that you can't assign stuff to variables that are declared in a different scope than the lambda but used in any lambda.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside lambda function all variable have to be final.

you can create your collect variable as Atomic and then you can assign on it your list:

```
 AtomicReference<List<FinalAssessment>> collect = null;
```